# how to select first item by default and then highlight the selected next item of json data in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-directive

This is my `customer.component.html`.I am using this component to display my json data as contact list

```
   <mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let filteredScreen of filteredScreens; index as i"   [ylbHigh]="color">
            <mat-card-header >
                <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image" >
                    <img mat-card-image class="list-img" src="{{filteredScreen?.img}}" >
                </div>
                <mat-card-title  [innerHTML]="filteredScreen.name | highlight: name"  [ylbHighlight]="color">
                        <p class="names" [ylbHighlight]="color">{{   filteredScreen?.name }}</p>
                </mat-card-title>

            </mat-card-header>
        </mat-card>
```

Here in my list if i click to to particular list item,Its background color and text color is changing,as shown in below image

[image]

I have used two `directives` to change background-color and text-color are as follows

`high.directive.ts`

```
    import {  Directive, ElementRef, HostListener,Input } from 
    '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
     selector: '[ylbHigh]'
     })
    export class HighDirective {

     constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @Input() defaultColor: string;

    @Input('ylbHigh') highlightColor: string;

    @HostListener('click') onMouseEnter() {
    this.highlight(this.highlightColor || '#e6e6e6');
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
     this.highlight(null);
    }

    private highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }

    }
```

`highlight.directive.ts`

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener,Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[ylbHighlight]'
    })
    export class HighlightDirective {

      constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @Input() defaultColor: string;

    @Input('ylbHighlight') highlightColor: string;

    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
      this.highlight(this.highlightColor || '#aa3c9f');
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
      this.highlight(null);
    }

    private highlight(color: string) {
      this.el.nativeElement.style.color = color;
    }



    }
```

Now onclick list item background color is changing but on leaving its going away,Can i make it such that onclick a particular item background-color has to appear until i select next item it should be displaying the background-color of the previous clicked item??

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711053/how-to-highlight-an-input-field-text-in-angular-6?rq=1

Comment: The answer is to highlight the the data entering in the search field,I want background color to be constant for first item,on clicking  the next item it has de select the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that directive that you have created could do what you are set to do because it wouldn't know if the directive (i.e. self) is #1.
But, what you could do it that to put those loop in a parent component and use `Query` in Angular (`@ContentChildren` - you can query by directives or component type) to gather the collection of children.

Comment: Its ok,Now onclick list item background color is changing but on leaving its going away,Can i make it such that onclick a particular item background-color has to appear until i select next item it should be displaying the background-color of the previous clicked item??

Comment: This is what i was actually looking for,Thank you.

Comment: If you could mark that as answered, that would be great :)